# clicking on a div to show and hide other divs in jquery

Tags: jquery

html code:

```
<div id="all"> </div>
<div id="div1"> </div>
<div id="div2"> </div>
<div id="div3"> </div>
<div id="div4"> </div>
<div id="div5"> </div>
```

jquery code:

This works for swithcing between "div1" and "all". What if I wanted to click on #div1 and show only "all" and hide the others and when clicked on "all", show all the divs.

```
    $(function () {
         $("#div1, #all").on('click', function () 
         {
             $("#div1, #all").not(this).show();
             $(this).hide(); 
         });
     });
```

Comment: explain the question correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below approach using `class`.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="all"> </div>
<div class="myDivs"> </div>
<div class="myDivs"> </div>
<div class="myDivs"> </div>
<div class="myDivs"> </div>
<div class="myDivs"> </div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.myDivs').click (function () {
        $('.myDivs').not(this).hide();
    });

    $('#all').click (function () {
        $('.myDivs').show();
    });
});
```

**Edit:** Improvised with 2 handlers

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Fsg9y/2/

Comment: Why switch to classes when all divs have ids and would be so much faster?

Comment: He has 5 div's now.. later if he has 20 div's then you wouldn't be writing that many `$('#div..')` right.. If you are talking about using attribute selector: it is `$('div[id^="div"]')` is much slower than class selector.

Comment: @Vega, this is very close to what I am trying to do. Let's say in your example, the second div is this: <div id="cpu" class="myDivs"> </div> when I click on the cpu, I should whow only the all div and hide all the others. Then when I click on All, show all the others. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1471980 Do you many other conditions like that or is it just `#cpu`? In case if it just 1 case.. then just remove `myDivs` class from `#cpu` and write a separate handler `$('#cpu').click (function () { $(this).add('#all').show(); });`

Comment: @Vega, I will actually have 10 cases where there will be cpu, memory, que, io, etc. you proably got what I am trying to do. When page loads, I have bunch of divs that have aggregate graphs. Each div is aggregated to show cpu, memory, que etc. When clicked on any of these graphs, I like to load individual graphs call "all" in this case. For example, page loads. When the users clicks on cpu aggregate graph, they see individual graphs for cpu. Nothing else. When the users clicks on all div, they go back to the previous seen and so and so forth.

Comment: @Vega, I think I got the idea. Thanks so much, this was really helpfull.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you need to do, using lovely selectors that jQuery provides

```
$(function () {
    $('div[id^="div"]').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings().filter(':not(#all)').hide();
    });

    $('#all').click(function() {
        $('div[id^="div"]').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: why not just use .not('#all') instead of filter("not())

Comment: @L0j1k yours is only shorter, until he needs to implement the logic. Yours does absolutely nothing aside from iterate through the divs, hence not answering the question asked by OP :-/

Comment: @Bryan Moyles, let me try this. Thank you.

Comment: @wirey very valid point my friend! I just typically use the selector, I'm not sure if there's a performance boost either way, but I would lean to say using.not('#all') would be better. btw L0j1k, way to downvote through your own immaturity ;)

Comment: Ah, this is far better than my answer. Thanks for the insight Bryan

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via the foreach function and providing the parent node's id:

```
$('div').each( function() {} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/sAW36/

```
(function($) {
    $('div[id^=div]').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.each($('div[id^=div]'), function() {
            if ($(this).attr('id') == id) return true;
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });

    $('div#all').click(function() {
        $('div[id^=div]').show();
    });
})(jQuery);​
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your divs won't actually be named "div1", div2, etc. In which case, you could do this:

```
$(function(){
    $("div").click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("id") === "all"){
            $(this).siblings().show();
        }
        else{
           $(this).siblings().not("#all").hide();
        }
    });       
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mPdCb/1

Comment: yes, div ids are different. They dont all start with divs. The ideas is this. I have some graphs that I load into bunch of divs. These graphs are aggregate graphs. When clicked on one of the divs, I like load another div that has some other graphs. Basically all div above has nothing to do with other divs. When clicked on all, I need to load another image and hide all the other divs on that page. And when clicked on the all div again, need to show all the other divs and hide all div.